# Basic quantum entanglement reference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement

What basic (first course for undergrads) quantum mechanics book would you recommend to read about entanglement?

Comment: If you just want to learn about entanglement, have a conversation with somebody you know that might know quantum mechanics, and don't let them hand-wave. Alternatively, you could read a little more about entanglement (though I would suggest starting at more fundamental concepts of quantum mechanics) and formulate a more specific question. In order to avoid hand-waving explanations, you will need to do this anyways.

Comment: I am already studying QM, and I wanted to expand my knowladge about this subject since what we studied in class is not enough for me.

Comment: Well, what do you know about entanglement already? Or, what book did you use for your class? (If you're interested in learning about quantum information theory, John Preskill has some excellent online notes on his website).

Comment: I agree with @fs137 - in different words, I think that it makes no sense to isolate "quantum entanglement" as a special subject to study. It's inseparable from quantum mechanics. When one understands quantum mechanics at a certain rather elementary level, he unavoidably sees what entangled states are and why they're omnipresent - really the generic states. They're simply defined as states that are not of the form $\psi_1\otimes \psi_2$ of the states of the subsystem, but only as a sum of several products like that. That's it - why it's possible, important, what is impossible etc. needs QM...

Comment: @fs137 All i pretty much know is the defintion as stated by Luboš Motl above. in class we only discussed one example -  two identical particles scatterd from a potential barrier, when each partical arrives from a different side of te barrier.

In class we mostly use Cohen-Tannoudji and sometimes Messiah, which both do not treat the subject (as far as I know). I would like to know where I can find some more examples and discussion.

Comment: Do you have a specific result in mind relating to entanglement that you are interested in learning (for example, entanglement distillation is a somewhat interesting topic)? Also, if you are using Messiah then you would certainly be ready to read Nielsen & Chuang's quantum information theory book. However, I personally recommend John Preskill's notes since they are free.